# While making app in flutter when I put OTP on my screen then it doesn't go to next page and in debug shows this error

Tags: flutter

when I put OTP like this then it shows nothing

[image]

This is the code to verify OTP

[image]

and it shows this in debug

[image]

how to resolve it?

I try many things but doesn't work for me in this case so please guide me accordingly.

Comment: Please note the code and error are text and should be included as formatted text in the question, not as images. And the whole error message should be included. Otherwise it’s difficult to help.

Comment: Why don't you just use Navigator.push?

Comment: I solved this issue. thanks